# Telegraf: "replyWithInvoice" isn't available for "callback_query::"

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have a `callback_query` when users hit on a purchase button. The `callback_query` is to send an invoice to the user, but it is throwing the above error.

```
bot.on('callback_query', (ctx) => {
    let data = ctx.callbackQuery.data
    if (data.includes('purchase') == true) {
        return handlePurchase(ctx)
    }
})

function handlePurchase(ctx) {
    let data = ctx.callbackQuery.data
    let itemId = data.split(':')[1]
    let invoice = {
        chat_id: ctx.callbackQuery.from.id,
        title: "Title",
        description: "Description",
        payload: itemId.toString(),
        provider_token: stripeToken,
        start_parameter: itemId.toString(),
        currency: "USD",
        need_phone_number: true,
        need_shipping_address: true,
        photo_url: the_image_url,
        prices: [{
            label: "Item",
            amount: 1000
        }]
    }
    return ctx.replyWithInvoice(invoice)
}
```

I also attempted to use `ctx.telegram.sendInvoice(invoice)` instead but the bot did not send an invoice to the user, ie the bot did not respond at all.